# Header file of Objective C delegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've just finished my Objective C class that is used as an `NSXMLParser` delegate. It contains a couple of `parser:` methods that `NSXMLParserDelegate` should implement and also my own `parserOutput` property and a new method called `initWithEncryptedFile:`.

Now, do I need to have those `parser:` methods in my `.h` file as well? Or is it enough to put there what's not described in `NSXMLParserDelegate`'s documentation?

Is it enough to write `.h` like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataFileParser : NSXMLParser <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableOrderedSet *parserOutput;

- (id) initWithEncryptedFile:(NSString *)path;

@end
```

Or should I mention also all `parser:` methods like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataFileParser : NSXMLParser <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableOrderedSet *parserOutput;

- (id) initWithEncryptedFile:(NSString *)path;
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)elementValue;
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName;

@end
```

Both versions work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first version is fine since you're declaring the `DataFileParser` conforms to that protocol.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ash! Glad it's the first one. :)

Comment: Me, too! That'd be an *insane* amount of typing for larger classes. If you're happy with my answer, remember to mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left.